# How can I verify user mobile number in laravel application after register user?

Tags: laravel

I want to send a user verification message after user register. How can I do this with laravel?

Comment: Hi Rakib, Welcome to StackOverflow. You have not included enough information in your question. please consider improving it - you can use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as a guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use SMS Gateway for sending verification code or OTP. you can follow this [link](https://codeforgeek.com/mobile-number-verification-using-laravel/) for reference

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Twilio](https://github.com/aloha/laravel-twilio).  The library is pretty solid and the api is relatively simple.